# SQL Query - Finding the duplicate fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm fairly new to the SQL game and I am trying to fill a gap in data verification for our accounts guys.

What I have is a table (`Truck_Invoice`) that has the following columns:

```
Invoice_ID, Invoice_Date, Docket_ID, Docket_Date.
```

What I have is multiple Docket_IDs to Invoice_IDs but we're finding duplicate Docket_IDs across multiple Invoice_IDs... I looking to find a way that I can create a query that I can run to produce a result of:

```
Invoice_ID   Docket_ID   Invoice_Date   Docket_Date    
1001         2000        01/03/2015     01/02/2015    
1005         2000        01/04/2015     01/02/2015
```

I appreciate any help you guys can help me with!

A pint to the person who can get me this win

Comment: To get the duplicate `Docket_Id` values you can use a query with  `GROUP BY Docket_Id` and `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` clauses. You can find plenty of examples here in SO addressing this problem.

Comment: What is the logic behind why these two particular records were retained?  Can you also show the sample input which generates this output?

Comment: Do you want the duplicate docket_id multiple times in the results? I think, I do not get the point of this question.

Comment: Thanks all for the quick feed back Tien Nguyen was on the money!  Thats exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Invoice_ID, Docket_ID, Invoice_Date, Docket_Date
FROM Truck_Invoice
WHERE Docket_ID IN 
(
SELECT Docket_ID FROM Truck_Invoice GROUP BY Docket_ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks Mate! That worked an absolute treat. 

I'm thinking - would there be a way to add a condition where I could add saying, if Docket_ID > 1 and Invoice_ID different.
.
What I have is multiple lines for the same docket, based on the items of the docket.

Answer (score 0):

Does sorting by Docket_ID solve your problem?

It looks like this query generates the result you are looking for;

```
SELECT Invoice_ID, Invoice_Date, Docket_ID, Docket_Date
FROM Truck_Invoice
ORDER BY Docket_ID
```